# Javascript Basic Increment and Decrement

Tags: javascript, increment, decrement

Why isn't `dec()` decreasing the value?

```
<div id="variableTest">8</div>
<label id="incButton" onclick="inc()">+</div> </br>   
<label id="decButton" onclick="dec()">-</div> </br>
    ​

function dec() {
    var testDec = document.getElementById("variableTest").innerHTML;
    testDec--;
}

function inc() {
    var testInc = document.getElementById("variableTest").innerHTML;
    testInc++;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fv6VA/8/

Comment: does that javascript even work? i did not know you could increment and decrement a string.

Comment: @jbabey you have no idea. http://wtfjs.com/

Comment: related: [WAT](http://www.shopify.com/technology/5370262-wat-a-funny-look-at-ruby-and-javascript-oddities)

Comment: What happens instead? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`element.innerHTML` returns a string, not a number. You should use something like this:

```
var element = document.getElementById("variableTest");
element_number = parseFloat(element.innerHTML);
element_number++;
element.innerHTML = element_number;
```

Comment: Thanks, I was having trouble converting to a number before.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you have made a copy of innerHTML, and are just decrementing it in javascript memory.  You haven't actually set the innerHTML of the variableTest node.

```
function dec() {
    var testDec = document.getElementById("variableTest").innerHTML;
    testDec--;
    document.getElementById("variableTest").innerHTML = testDec;
}
```

UPDATE

Also, your HTML is messed up.  You need to close your `label` properly

```
<div id="variableTest">8</div>
<label id="incButton" onclick="inc()">+</label> </br>   
<label id="decButton" onclick="dec()">-</label> </br>
```

Comment: Sloppy copy/paste job on my part :)  hvgotcodes solution is better

Comment: I'm using this method but now why doesnt inc() work?

Live Link: http://jsfiddle.net/fv6VA/8/

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="container">
<input type="button" onclick="decrementValue()" value="-" />
<input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" maxlength="2" max="10" size="1" id="number" />
<input type="button" onclick="incrementValue()" value="+" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function incrementValue()
{
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    if(value<10){
        value++;
            document.getElementById('number').value = value;
    }
}
function decrementValue()
{
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    if(value>1){
        value--;
            document.getElementById('number').value = value;
    }

}
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question - you've just used the question as a segue to your blog.

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.